# command line method or programmatically add ssh key to github.com user account

Tags: ssh, terminal, git, github

Is there a way to identify with a username and password to github.com servers for the purpose of adding an ssh key to the github user account? So far everything I've read suggests that a user's ssh key must be added via the web GUI. I'm looking for the method or process of adding a key via a command line interface or else a bash/ansible/something script.

Comment: How about using [some library](https://developer.github.com/libraries/) to use [GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### **Update 2020**

As stated in [developer changes](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/), Password authentication is going to be deprecated at:

**November 13, 2020 at 16:00 UTC**

Additionally, as @trysis asked in the comments, we need a solution for 2FA.

The new way is to use a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token):
[image]

For our specific example (adding a ssh key), we only need write permissions (read permissions are added automatically on using write permissions):
[image]

The updated command (via curl):

```
curl -H "Authorization: token YourGeneratedToken" --data '{"title":"test-key","key":"ssh-rsa AAA..."}' https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

This does also work when 2FA is enabled.

---

### **OLD**

Auth with username and password is [supported by github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication):

> There are three ways to authenticate through GitHub API v3.
> ...
> Basic Authentication
> $ curl -u "username" https://api.github.com
> ...

So just [choose a lib](https://developer.github.com/libraries/) in the language you prefer
and use the implemented version of the *[Create a Public Key](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/#create-a-public-key)* "Public Key" API Section:

> Creates a public key. Requires that you are authenticated via Basic Auth, or OAuth with at least [write:public_key] scope.

**INPUT**
`POST /user/keys`

```
{
    "title": "octocat@octomac",
    "key": "ssh-rsa AAA..."
}
```

If you want to use it from command line (via curl):

```
curl -u "username" --data '{"title":"test-key","key":"ssh-rsa AAA..."}' https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

or even without prompting for password:

```
curl -u "username:password" --data '{"title":"test-key","key":"ssh-rsa AAA..."}' https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

here is a nice little tutorial for [using curl to interact with github API](https://gist.github.com/btoone/2288960)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of information I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you add 2-Factor auth? Otherwise, the answer is amazing, even 6 years later!

Answer (score 8):

Similar to xx4h's answer, this is how I do it in scripts for automating new VM setups.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemailaddress@hotmail.com"
curl -u "myusername" \
    --data "{\"title\":\"DevVm_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`\",\"key\":\"`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`\"}" \
    https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

It gives you a new SSH key, includes it in the curl call and gives a unique but still easily identifiable name for each one on the GitHub side (e.g. running now would give DevVm_150602142247).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -xe
myemail="your-email"

#your personal access token
git_api_token="befdf14c152d6f2ad8cff9c5affffffffffffffffff"

#We'll use the HTTPS to push a ssh key to git, SSH for pull/push configuration
gitrepo_ssh="git@github.com:person/repo.git"
gitrepo_https="https://github.com/person/repo.git"

#Generating SSH key:
ssh-keygen -f "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa" -t rsa -b 4096 -C "${myemail}" -N ''
sslpub="$(cat ${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub |tail -1)"

#git API path for posting a new ssh-key:
git_api_addkey="https://api.$(echo ${gitrepo_https} |cut -d'/' -f3)/user/keys"

#lets name the ssh-key in get after the hostname with a timestamp:
git_ssl_keyname="$(hostname)_$(date +%d-%m-%Y)"

#Finally lets post this ssh key:
curl -H "Authorization: token ${git_api_token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"title\":\"${git_ssl_keyname}\",\"key\":\"${sslpub}\"}" ${git_api_addkey}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an API token... I use the following on our internal gitLab server

snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

myemail="first.last@domain.com"

# User API token can be found: "https://git.labs.domain.com/profile/account"
git_api_token="m3iP27Jh8KSgNmWAksYp"

# We'll use the HTTPS to push a ssh key to git, SSH for pull/push configuration
gitrepo_ssh="git@git.labs.domain.com:devops/automation.git"
gitrepo_https="https://git.labs.domain.com/devops/automation.git"

########################]  D O   N O T   C H A N G E  [########################

# Generating SSH key:
ssh-keygen -f "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa" -t rsa -b 4096 -C "${myemail}" -N ''
sslpub="$(cat ${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub |tail -1)"

# git API path for posting a new ssh-key:
git_api_addkey="https://$(echo ${gitrepo_https} |cut -d'/' -f3)/api/v3/user/keys"

# lets name the ssh-key in get after the hostname with a timestamp:
git_ssl_keyname="$(hostname)-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"

# Finally lets post this ssh key:
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${git_api_token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST -d "{\"title\":\"${git_ssl_keyname}\",\"key\":\"${sslpub}\"}"     \
    ${git_api_addkey}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new [GitHub CLI gh](https://cli.github.com/), you have [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) +  [`gh ssh add`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_ssh-key_add)

> Add an SSH key to your GitHub account
>
> ```
> gh ssh-key add [<key-file>] [flags]
> ```